# Windows Server 2008 not handling exceptions

Tags: c#-4.0, exception

Sorry for shouting...just a bit excited to be here.

Anyway, we have recently moved a bunch of console applications (written in C#, .net 4) to new windows server 2008 machines. All the code executing in these apps are in a try block, we can't have them crashing. This worked fine on the old machines, but now whenever an exception is caught the server throws up the "is not working" dialog. This are apps that contact not-very-reliable web services, and we catch a lot of exceptions. So in a day or so, the desktop is cluttered with these windows, and I every time I spend 20 minutes closing them all, I die little inside. Any ideas on why this is happening? My Google searches have been fruitless.

Comment: What does code do once it catches an exception?

Comment: Just spits the message out and closes. In some cases, they get logged, if I need to know what happened.

Comment: Actually, I found a way to disable the window on Server Exchange.

http://serverfault.com/questions/29678/disabling-myapp-has-stopped-working-dialog

So there you go...I guess maybe the registry was just set differently on those old machines.